# Access an iPads Device Settings using UIAutomation

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation, xcode5.0.1

Can you access the iPad Device settings using the UIAutomation instrument? 
I can use deactivateAppForDuration, but that does not allow me to exit the app navigate to the settings page, change a setting, and navigate back to the app and move on.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot automate anything outside of the target application as of right now. When your app leaves the foreground the automation tool loses control until it returns (if it does at least).